# Get the position of the largest value in a multi-dimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy

How can I get get the position (indices) of the largest value in a multi-dimensional NumPy array?

Comment: In case there are multiple positions with equally large values, do you need them all or only the first (or last or just any)?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The [`argmax()`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-e2829234dedbedccc333d32ee2738c28777f2e94) method should help.

**Update**

(After reading comment) I believe the `argmax()` method would work for multi dimensional arrays as well. The linked documentation gives an example of this:

```
>>> a = array([[10,50,30],[60,20,40]])
>>> maxindex = a.argmax()
>>> maxindex
3
```

**Update 2**

(Thanks to [KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm)'s comment) You can use `unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)` to get the index as a tuple:

```
>>> from numpy import unravel_index
>>> unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
(1, 0)
```

Comment: But i have a multidimensional array.

Comment: Use `unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)` to get the index as a tuple.

Comment: what does number 3 mean? Okay i see. I was looking for (1,0).

Comment: there should really be a built-in function for getting the value as a tuple

Comment: unravel_index docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html

Answer (score 7):

(edit) I was referring to **an old answer which had been deleted**. And the accepted answer came after mine. I agree that `argmax` is better than my answer.

Wouldn't it be more readable/intuitive to do like this?

```
numpy.nonzero(a.max() == a)
(array([1]), array([0]))
```

Or,

```
numpy.argwhere(a.max() == a)
```

Comment: Needlessly slow, because you compute the max and then compare it to all of a.  unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape).

Comment: I voted for this because it assumes nothing about the number of occurrences of a.max() in a. Whereas a.argmax() will return the "first" occurrence (which is ill-defined in the case of a multi-dimensional array since it depends on the choice of traversal path). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax  I also think np.where() is a more natural/readable chose rather than np.nonzero().

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write a function (that works only in 2d):

```
def argmax_2d(matrix):
    maxN = np.argmax(matrix)
    (xD,yD) = matrix.shape
    if maxN >= xD:
        x = maxN//xD
        y = maxN % xD
    else:
        y = maxN
        x = 0
    return (x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is change `numpy` array to `list` and use `max` and `index` methods:

```
List = np.array([34, 7, 33, 10, 89, 22, -5])
_max = List.tolist().index(max(List))
_max
>>> 4
```