# How can I find where a vector value passes a threshold and the n+1 value meets a condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

Here's what I have so far:

`locs = np.where((v_1 >= 1.9) & (v_1 <= 2.00))`

I just want to add the condition that the next element (after the one where `v_1` meets the current conditions) is larger than the found element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself!

(see [Finding local maxima/minima with Numpy in a 1D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array) )

```
locs = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(v_1))) < 0).nonzero()[0] +1
```