# Large list, find all minima of list

Tags: python, list

Given a large list of fluctuating values, how do you determine all local min values? Not using *numpy*. Local minimum means all values in a list that are the troughs of a function.

```
List_y = [23, 8, -7, 57, 87, 6]
```

I would like:

```
New_list = [-7, 6]
```

Comment: If the number is less than the two on either side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding local maxima/minima with Numpy in a 1D numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array)

Comment: There's no numpy mention here. Don't assume that people automatically have external libraries.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific on what "local min values" means. Edit your question and gives us some expected input / output.

Comment: What should `[23, 6, 6, 6, 42]` return?

Comment: I didn't even think of that... wow! I guess it would need to be [6] because i only need one value of minima appended to another list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def local_min(ys):
    return [y for i, y in enumerate(ys)
            if ((i == 0) or (ys[i - 1] >= y))
            and ((i == len(ys) - 1) or (y < ys[i+1]))]


>>> local_min([23, 8, -7, 57, 87, 6])
[-7, 6]
>>> local_min([23, 6, 6, 6, 42])
[6]
>>> local_min([6, 6, 4])
[4]
```

Comment: Given `[6, 6, 4]`, you'll print `[6, 4]`.

Comment: @BillLynch: I changed it the other way, can you help me to spot other flaws?

Comment: Given `[4, 6, 6]`, you'll print `[4, 6]`.

Comment: But `6` isn't a local minima at all in the list `[4, 6, 6]`. Oh well.

Comment: @JohnGubba: Bill is right, 6 is more like a maximum. You should have better defined your question.

Comment: @enrico.bacis: Personally, this problem is infinitely easier if we preprocess the list to remove adjacent duplicates. All of my annoying cases are depending on that.

Comment: @BillLynch: I also thought about that

Comment: @BillLynch meant [4, 6, 6] ---> 4 is min.. sry

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of iterating over these problems in stages.

```
l = [23, 8, -7, -7, 57, 87, 6]

# Remove identical neighbors
# l becomes [23, 8, -7, 57, 87, 6]
l = [x for x,y in zip(l[0:], l[1:]) if x != y] + [l[-1]]

# Append positive infinity to both endpoints
# l becomes [inf, 23, 8, -7, 57, 87, 6, inf]
l = [float("inf")] + l + [float("inf")]

# Retain elements where each of their neighbors are greater than them.
# l becomes [-7, 6]
l = [y for x, y, z in zip(l[0:], l[1:], l[2:]) if x > y < z]
```

Comment: i think it's underappreciated :)

Comment: As I understand it from its definition, the minima isn't strictly _smaller_ than its neighbors, but may be equal to (either of) them. Thus, I think your _Remove identical neighbors_ step may be eliminated, and the code be:

`>>> l = [23, 8, -7, -7, 57, 87, 6]`
>>> l = [float("inf")] + l + [float("inf")]
`>>> l = [y for x, y, z in zip(l[0:], l[1:], l[2:]) if x >= y <= z]`
>>> l
`[-7, -7, 6]`

Comment: @boardrider: Then `3 4 4 4 3` would report `3 4 3` which is wrong. In addition, in the comments, John said that he was fine with only getting `-7, -6` from the input you suggest. I agree that a more accurate solution would have `-7 -7 6`, but creating that answer is harder with list comprehensions.

Comment: @Bill, why is `3 4 3` wrong (if we take the definition of minimal to be <=) ? `3` is the minimal of `None and 3`, `4` is the minimal of `4 4 4`, and `3` is the minimal of `3 and None`. What don't I get?

Comment: @boardrider: John never fully clarified what he meant by minima. It's certainly possible that the definition you're suggesting is what he was looking for. Personally, I'm considering this more like a function. So we can't just look at neighbors.