# Finding local minimum in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm

I need an algorithm which can find local minimum in an array

Comment: What have you tried this far?

Comment: I'll add that I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29614405/3080723) is much better than the accepted answer, for the duplicate question mkrieger1 linked.