# The tool for first peak detection (find first shifted value in continuous from array)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I have array of peak intensity where is plotted like

[image]

Is there any tool for python that I can get the point where it has the first peak shifted from the baseline (red arrow)?

It seems like easy problem when I look by the eye for detection but for the code, what I can think is I have to define the minimum value peak intensity (in fixed number or percentage). I don't want to fix any value but want the code to detect peak differently by data. Is it possible by `scipy` or something?

Comment: There are a few Python packages out there that deal specifically with configurable peak detection with various methods. Have you taken a look for this on Github?

Comment: with noisy data you need a threshold to reject the noise

Comment: How do you define peak? As @f5r5e5d says, you first need to find a way to deal with noise and clearly define what a peak would be (and probably also do some additional smoothing). Depending on your data, you might then even get away with a simple approach as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070563/find-all-local-maxima-and-minima-when-x-and-y-values-are-given-as-numpy-arrays/31073798#31073798). But as sytech says, there should be plenty of tools out there...