# Finding maxima, above a certain threshold, with Numpy in a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My goal is to identify times (in datetime format below) at which there is a local maximum **above a certain threshold**. I appreciate there are other related responses which deal with numpy and scipy techniques for finding local maxima and minima, but none to my knowledge address a threshold level.

I have the following pandas.Series, represented as df_1, which stores integer values for given times:

```
t_min
2015-12-26 14:45:00      46
2015-12-26 14:46:00      25
2015-12-26 14:47:00      39
2015-12-26 14:48:00      58
2015-12-26 14:49:00      89
2015-12-26 14:50:00      60
2015-12-26 14:51:00      57
2015-12-26 14:52:00      60
2015-12-26 14:53:00      46
2015-12-26 14:54:00      31
2015-12-26 14:55:00      66
2015-12-26 14:56:00      78
2015-12-26 14:57:00      49
2015-12-26 14:58:00      47
2015-12-26 14:59:00      31
2015-12-26 15:00:00      55
2015-12-26 15:01:00      19
2015-12-26 15:02:00      10
2015-12-26 15:03:00      31
2015-12-26 15:04:00      36
2015-12-26 15:05:00      61
2015-12-26 15:06:00      29
2015-12-26 15:07:00      32
2015-12-26 15:08:00      49
2015-12-26 15:09:00      35
2015-12-26 15:10:00      17
2015-12-26 15:11:00      22
```

I use the following to deduce the array indexes at which local maxima occurs as per a response in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array):

```
x = np.array(df_1, dtype=np.float)

# for local maxima
print argrelextrema(x, np.greater)
```

However I wish to produce **an array of the TIMES at which these maxima occur** and not the integer (now converted to float) values at these indexes as I could find using `x[argrelextrema(x, np.greater)[0]]` – any idea how I could obtain an array of said times?

Proceeding this I also aim to refine this list of times by **only selecting maxima above a certain threshold**, i.e. whose slope is above a certain limit. This would allow me to avoid obtaining every single local maxima but instead to identify the most significant “peaks”. Would anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the peaks by taking the difference between shifted x-arrays:

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
array([ 46.,  25.,  39.,  58.,  89.,  60.,  57.,  60.,  46.,  31.,  66.,
        78.,  49.,  47.,  31.,  55.,  19.,  10.,  31.,  36.,  61.,  29.,
        32.,  49.,  35.,  17.,  22.])

In [15]: x[1:] - x[:-1]
Out[15]: 
array([-21.,  14.,  19.,  31., -29.,  -3.,   3., -14., -15.,  35.,  12.,
       -29.,  -2., -16.,  24., -36.,  -9.,  21.,   5.,  25., -32.,   3.,
        17., -14., -18.,   5.])
```

The values of `x[1:] - x[:-1]` give the "slope" between the values of `x`. By picking where this slope changes from positive to negative you can find out the indices of the peaks in your original array.

```
In [33]: slope = x[1:] - x[:-1]

In [34]: indices = [i+1 for i in range(len(slope)-1) if slope[i] > 0 and slope[i+1] < 0]

In [35]: indices
Out[35]: [4, 7, 11, 15, 20, 23]

In [36]: [x[j] for j in indices]
Out[36]: [89, 60, 78, 55, 61, 49]
```

I didn't bother to make a list of the time, but since you hace the indices...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually using the method I mentioned above `argrelextrema` from `scipy.signal` as follows:

`x = np.array(df_1, dtype=np.float)
    # for local maxima
    print argrelextrema(x, np.greater)`

which gives me the array [4, 7, 11, 15, 20, 23] however I am looking to return the times from the original data frame that these indices refer to. Would you have any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a list out of the first column in the dataframe (let's call that `d`), and index that: `[d[j] for j in indices]`.

Answer (score 1):

As of SciPy version 1.1, you can also use [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html):

```
import numpy as np                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

x = np.array([ 46.,  25.,  39.,  58.,  89.,  60.,  57.,  60.,  46.,  31.,  66.,
        78.,  49.,  47.,  31.,  55.,  19.,  10.,  31.,  36.,  61.,  29.,
        32.,  49.,  35.,  17.,  22.])

peaks, _ = find_peaks(x)

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

This will plot will get all local maxima:

[image]

If you now want to use a threshold (e.g. 60), you can use (rest of the code identical):

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=60)
```

This will plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, all you need to do after you used the `argrelextrema` is to apply these indices to the times. Provided your initial snippet:

```
x = np.array(df_1, dtype=np.float)

# for local maxima
print argrelextrema(x, np.greater)
```

All you need to do is modify it like this:

```
indices = argrelextrema(x, np.greater)
df_1['time'] = df_1.index # to turn your times into a column of a dataframe - they are currently in index, right?

# So your solution is this:
print df_1.ix[indices[0], 'time']  # the [0] is there because argrelextrema returns a tuple of the array of indices and dtype, so the first item of the tuple are the indices themselves
```