# How to find peaks in 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, kinect

I am reading a csv file in python and preparing a dataframe out of it. I have a Microsoft Kinect which is recording Arm Abduction exercise and generating this CSV file.

I have [this array](https://pastebin.com/53QYNJ4k) of Y-Coordinates of ElbowLeft joint. You can visualize this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFMgo.png). Now, I want to come up with a solution which can count number of peaks or local maximum in this array.

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt`.

Comment: The newer `scipy.signal.find_peaks` may work better, unless you are really sure you need to use wavelet convolution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding local maxima/minima with Numpy in a 1D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to smooth the data with a smoothing filter and then find all values where the value before and after are less than the current value. This assumes you want all peaks in the sequence. The reason you need the smoothing filter is to avoid local maxima. The level of smoothing required will depend on the noise present in your data.

A simple smoothing filter sets the current value to the average of the N values before and N values after the current value in your sequence along with the current value being analyzed.

Comment: I used moving average smoothing to smooth it (with np.convolve). And used argrelextrema from scipy.signal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **find_peaks_cwt** function from the **scipy.signal** module to find peaks within 1-D arrays:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

y_coordinates = np.array(y_coordinates) # convert your 1-D array to a numpy array if it's not, otherwise omit this line
peak_widths = np.arange(1, max_peak_width)
peak_indices = signal.find_peaks_cwt(y_coordinates, peak_widths)
peak_count = len(peak_indices) # the number of peaks in the array
```

More information here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, put the data in a 1-d array and compare each value with the neighboors, the n-1 and n+1 data are smaller than n.

Read data as Robert Valencia suggests

```
   max_local=0
for u in range (1,len(data)-1):

if ((data[u]>data[u-1])&(data[u]>data[u+1])):
                            max_local=max_local+1
```

Comment: This algo will fail for input like data = [3,2,3,6,4,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,1]