# Finding local maxima with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, signal-processing, data-science

I am looking for a way to get the indices of the local maxima of a tensor using TensorFlow exclusively.

**tl;dr**

I am not a data scientist.  I don't know much about the theory behind much of computer vision, but I am trying to build a computer vision app using TensorFlow.  I plan on saving my model and calling it as a service using TF Serving, so I can't depend on external libraries such as numpy, scipy, etc.  What I want to accomplish is algorithmically the same as scipy's signal.argrelextrema, but in a way that can be saved with my model and rerun.  Other algorithms for this have been shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array), but none execute within TensorFlow. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

My first solution was functional, but inefficient.  It required five iterations of the tensor (zero-trail, reverse, zero-trail, reverse, where).  I now have a solution that requires only two iterations, and is also flexible enough to quickly identify local minima as well...

```
def get_slope(prev, cur):
    # A: Ascending
    # D: Descending
    # P: PEAK (on previous node)
    # V: VALLEY (on previous node)
    return tf.cond(prev[0] < cur, lambda: (cur, ascending_or_valley(prev, cur)), lambda: (cur, descending_or_peak(prev, cur)))

def ascending_or_valley(prev, cur):
    return tf.cond(tf.logical_or(tf.equal(prev[1], 'A'), tf.equal(prev[1], 'V')), lambda: np.array('A'), lambda: np.array('V'))

def descending_or_peak(prev, cur):
    return tf.cond(tf.logical_or(tf.equal(prev[1], 'A'), tf.equal(prev[1], 'V')), lambda: np.array('P'), lambda: np.array('D'))

def label_local_extrema(tens):
    """Return a vector of chars indicating ascending, descending, peak, or valley slopes"""
    # initializer element values don't matter, just the type.
    initializer = (np.array(0, dtype=np.float32), np.array('A'))
    # First, get the slope for each element
    slope = tf.scan(get_slope, tens, initializer)
    # shift by one, since each slope indicator is the slope
    # of the previous node (necessary to identify peaks and valleys)
    return slope[1][1:]

def find_local_maxima(tens):
    """Return the indices of the local maxima of the first dimension of the tensor"""
    return tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(label_local_extrema(blur_x_tf), 'P')))
```

**End EDIT**

Ok, I've managed to find a solution, but it's not pretty.  The following function takes a 1D tensor, and reduces all points that are not local maxima to zero.  This will work only for positive numbers, and would require modification for datatypes other than float32, but it meets my needs.

There has to be a better way to do this, though.

```
def zero_descent(prev, cur):
    """reduces all descent steps to zero"""
    return tf.cond(prev[0] < cur, lambda: (cur, cur), lambda: (cur, 0.0))

def skeletonize_1d(tens):
    """reduces all point other than local maxima to zero"""
    # initializer element values don't matter, just the type.
    initializer = (np.array(0, dtype=np.float32), np.array(0, dtype=np.float32))
    # First, zero out the trailing side
    trail = tf.scan(zero_descent, tens, initializer)
    # Next, let's make the leading side the trailing side
    trail_rev = tf.reverse(trail[1], [0])
    # Now zero out the leading (now trailing) side
    lead = tf.scan(zero_descent, trail_rev, initializer)
    # Finally, undo the reversal for the result
    return tf.reverse(lead[1], [0])

def find_local_maxima(tens):
    return tf.where(skeletonize_1d >0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pseudo:**

```
input_matrix == max_pool(input_matrix)
```

**Explanation:**

When input values are the same as the ones taken by max_pooling, it means they are the greatest around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are giving enough information to clarify much. First of all, I'm not sure you want to get the maximum element of a Tensor (there is a function in tf for this) or you want to find the local maxima of a function (not a Tensor). In this case, you can revert the function and find the local minima which would result in what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for the local maxima, not the absolute maximum.  In other words, I would like to know the indices of all the peaks.  A peak occurs every time the slope of the tensor changes from positive to negative.  See https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cRng.png for a graphical example.