# Extract all minima from an array:

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array in `numpy` which reads:

`arr = np.array([[1,2,7,6],[2,3,2,1],[10,8,1,3],[9,7,4,2], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])`

I would like to extract all entries where surrounding entries are superior. A sort of 'local minima' such that I obtain the following indices:

`indices = [(0,0), [(2,2), (2,3)]]`

Note that the second item in the list is a list of tuples. I would like for such an algorithm to be able to identify local minimum areas as well as local minimum points. NAN values should simply be ignored and treated like a "border".

I have tried playing around with `np.gradient` because I thought that it should allow me to extract parts where the derivative is 0. But I couldn't really get it to a point where it would work.

Do any libraries or out-of-the-box functionalities exist to achieve this?

Comment: surroundings, as in both axis?

Comment: exactly. Both axes are important. If there are any NAN values I also want them to act as a border. For instance `np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [8,1,3], [7,4,2]]) `should yield`[(1,1)]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array

Comment: @Aly Hosny That's for a 1D array. That's easy...