# A way to get the local minima and maxima of a vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector, minimum

I've been trying to retrieve the extrema of a vector that looks like this :

[![First case][1]][1]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/25/4/1561063354-figure-1.png))</sub>

or like this :
[![Second case][2]][2]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/25/4/1561063360-figure-2-complexe.png))</sub>

I've been trying to retrieve local maxima and minima, it works well with :
`(diff(sign(diff(values_right_vector))) > 0).nonzero()[0] + 1` but afterwards it is only workaround and workaround because there is always a case where my previous workaround fails..

It has always this same pattern.

Do you have any ideas how can I retrieve those maxima and minima no matter the input vector (`left` and `right`) on the image.

Here is a sample :

````
[-2.7, -2.5, -2.1, -2.1, -1.8, -1.4, -0.9, -0.2, 0.5, 1.4, 2.2, 2.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.3, 2.3, 1.1, -0.5, -2.1, -3.5, -4.7, -5.5, -5.8, -5.6, -5.0, -4.2, -3.3, -2.3, -1.4, -0.8, -0.3, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.4, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.0, -0.4, -0.9, -1.3, -1.5, -1.6, -1.5, -1.1, -0.5, 0.2, 1.2, 2.1, 3.0, 3.8, 4.3, 4.3, 4.0, 3.2, 1.9, 0.4, -1.3, -3.0, -4.4, -5.4, -6.0, -6.0, -5.6, -4.8, -3.9, -2.9, -1.9, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.3, -0.5, -0.7, -0.9, -1.1, -1.1, -1.0, -0.8, -0.4, 0.3, 1.1, 1.9, 2.8, 3.6, 4.2, 4.5, 4.5, 4.1, 3.4, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, -0.5, -1.4, -2.1, -2.8, -3.3, -3.7, -3.9, -3.9, -3.8, -3.4, -2.9, -2.2, -1.3, -0.4, 0.7, 1.7, 2.5, 3.2, 3.6, 3.6, 3.2, 2.4, 1.3, -0.1, -1.6, -3.0, -4.1, -4.9, -5.1, -5.0, -4.4, -3.6, -2.7, -1.8, -1.1, -0.5, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1]```

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3er1.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbqNK.png
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local maxima/minima with Numpy in a 1D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate, as I explained after retrieving those extrema points, I need to parse them and it is only workaround after workaround..

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that exhibits this pattern?

Comment: Also, what explicitly is your criteria for choosing extrema?

Comment: The criteria is the extrema showed in green. For the maxima it is pretty simple, just take maxima via the formula I gave and threshold all "false" maxima below the `global max - threshold`
For the minima it is always the second "drop" after the maxima (but for the second picture there is a trick because it starts with only the first one..)

Comment: post up some sample data if you want careful help

Comment: done :) I don't think it is solvable with a general deterministic algorithm.. There is too much cases. The second one above proves it.. 
If you have an idea don't hesitate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy has a `find_peaks` function that you can manipulate to find the peaks you want using the `distance` parameter. The `distance` parameter tells Scipy how many spaces between samples it should look for peaks. You can adjust this to fit your data best. Using just the sample data you provided,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([-2.7, -2.5, -2.1, -2.1, -1.8, -1.4, -0.9, -0.2, 0.5, 1.4, 2.2, 2.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.3, 2.3, 1.1, -0.5, -2.1, -3.5, -4.7, -5.5, -5.8, -5.6, -5.0, -4.2, -3.3, -2.3, -1.4, -0.8, -0.3, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.4, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.0, -0.4, -0.9, -1.3, -1.5, -1.6, -1.5, -1.1, -0.5, 0.2, 1.2, 2.1, 3.0, 3.8, 4.3, 4.3, 4.0, 3.2, 1.9, 0.4, -1.3, -3.0, -4.4, -5.4, -6.0, -6.0, -5.6, -4.8, -3.9, -2.9, -1.9, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, -0.3, -0.5, -0.7, -0.9, -1.1, -1.1, -1.0, -0.8, -0.4, 0.3, 1.1, 1.9, 2.8, 3.6, 4.2, 4.5, 4.5, 4.1, 3.4, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, -0.5, -1.4, -2.1, -2.8, -3.3, -3.7, -3.9, -3.9, -3.8, -3.4, -2.9, -2.2, -1.3, -0.4, 0.7, 1.7, 2.5, 3.2, 3.6, 3.6, 3.2, 2.4, 1.3, -0.1, -1.6, -3.0, -4.1, -4.9, -5.1, -5.0, -4.4, -3.6, -2.7, -1.8, -1.1, -0.5, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, -0.1, -0.1])

# Get the maxima and minima
maxima, _ = find_peaks(y, distance = 50)
minima, _ = find_peaks(-y, distance = 50)
```

`find_peaks` returns the indices of the peaks, which is why we can use `-y` to get the minima.

You can also index the `maxima` and `minima` to select the peaks you want, by doing something like `maxima[::2]` to select every other maxima.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(y)
ax.plot(maxima, y[maxima], 'x')
ax.plot(minima, y[minima], 'x')
plt.show()
```

[image]