# find local maximum in a column of a text file

Tags: python, max

I have a text file which contain two rows. I want to find local maximums of first row. I am trying below code, but I do not know why I get this error: "`x` must be a 1D array"

```
f= open ('ttt.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    c=line.split(' ')[0]
    d=float (c)
    a= np.array (d)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(a, height=0)
```

The input is like this:

```
0 5 
1 5
2 5
3 6
1 6
0 7
0 6
0.01 5
0.4 5
0.001 5
0.3 6
0.7 6
1.5 7
4 6
2 5
0.1 6
0 6
```

The output should be:

```
3 6
0.4 5
4 6
```

Comment: Please have a look at [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit the question by sharing a sample of your data.

Comment: Do you mean local maximums of the first column?  where does '7' come from?

Comment: There's nothing named `x` in your code snippet. Please post a proper minimal reproducible example.

Comment: 'x' comes in the error. This is part of calculation of the code in python!!

Answer (score 1):

`a` should be a list, however, you are not making a list.

```
f = open ('ttt.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
a = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in data]
a = np.array(a)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(a, height=0)
```

Comment: That is working. Thank you. But how could I know that "a" should be a list, because I had an error which was "x must be a 1D array".

Comment: I guess `x` is a variable name in `find_peaks` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`argrelextrema`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) from `scipy.signal`. It returns the index in the array.

Also, to load data from file, you can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). It returns data in a `numpy` array (ready to use).

Here the code:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np 
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

# Load the data from text file
data = np.loadtxt('ttt.txt')

# Get local maxima from the first column
index = argrelextrema(data[:, 0], np.greater)

print(index)
# (array([ 3,  8, 13], dtype=int64),)
print(data[index])
# [[3.  6. ]
#  [0.4 5. ]
#  [4.  6. ]]
```

[Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array)