# Finding the prominent peaks in data

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find the prominent peaks of some sets of data. One of my data sets looks like the following:

[image: Data Set 1]

As you can see in this there is a clear peak at approx w = -1.6. This is a prominent peak as there are no other peaks in the data set that are more than 10% of its height. So I store this w value as it is a prominent peak.

I also have another data set:

[image: Data Set 2]

Here you can see I have a large peak at approx w = 1.6. However, there is also a peak at approx w = 0.9 which has a Spectral Power that is larger than 10% of the largest peak. So I do not store this w value as it is not a prominent peak.

I am trying to create a function so that for a given set of Spectral power called y. The function checks if the largest peak is prominent (i.e there are no other peaks that are more than 10% the size of the largest peak). If largest peak is prominent then it prints the w value the peak occurs at. If it is not prominent then it prints("Not prominent").

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths, peak_prominences

def check_prominent_peaks(y):
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
        
    peak_heights = y[peaks]
        
    # Find the peak with the maximum height
    max_peak_index = np.argmax(peak_heights)
    max_peak_height = peak_heights[max_peak_index]

    threshold = 10

    # Check if the maximum peak 10 times larger than the others
    if max_peak_height > threshold * np.max(peak_heights[peak_heights != max_peak_height]):
        print(w[peaks][max_peak_index])
            
    else:
        print("Not Prominent")
```

However, this includes each individual data point as a peak. I want an individual peak to be the combination of the data points. Below is a snippet of the data.

```
w_data1 = np.array([-3.14159265e+00, -3.03687290e+00, -2.77507351e+00, -2.61799388e+00,
       -2.35619449e+00, -2.09439510e+00, -1.80641578e+00, -1.72787596e+00,
       -1.71740398e+00, -1.61268423e+00, -1.60744824e+00, -1.60221225e+00,
       -1.59697627e+00, -1.59174028e+00, -1.58650429e+00, -1.58126830e+00,
       -1.57079633e+00, -1.56556034e+00, -1.56032435e+00, -1.55508836e+00,
       -1.54985238e+00, -1.51843645e+00, -1.46607657e+00, -1.41371669e+00,
       -1.36135682e+00, -1.30899694e+00, -1.04719755e+00, -7.85398163e-01,
       -5.23598776e-01, -2.61799388e-01, -4.44089210e-16,  2.61799388e-01,
        5.23598776e-01,  1.04719755e+00,  1.57079633e+00,  2.09439510e+00,
        2.61799388e+00])

PS_data1 = array([1.95875121e+01, 2.17955953e+01, 3.02014494e+01, 3.86345651e+01,
       6.58105570e+01, 1.46458509e+02, 8.09563221e+02, 2.21754612e+04,
       6.40104090e+02, 5.20057432e+05, 1.28551555e+05, 1.25288212e+05,
       8.11800261e+04, 1.40052558e+06, 9.64441464e+05, 2.08724844e+06,
       9.40242662e+05, 2.61656013e+04, 1.32967749e+05, 1.22127952e+05,
       1.23733666e+05, 3.60411360e+03, 2.00470602e+04, 4.04207652e+03,
       1.10741091e+04, 5.54534985e+02, 5.58959484e+01, 5.58399196e+00,
       3.91053138e+01, 2.73404280e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.59311017e+01,
       2.25706295e+01, 1.01049830e+02, 2.22757819e+02, 1.27038938e+01,
       1.34606021e+01])

w_data2 = array([-2.61799388e+00, -2.09439510e+00, -1.57079633e+00, -1.04719755e+00,
       -8.48230016e-01, -8.42994029e-01, -8.37758041e-01, -8.32522053e-01,
       -8.27286065e-01, -8.22050078e-01, -8.16814090e-01, -8.11578102e-01,
       -8.06342114e-01, -8.01106127e-01, -7.95870139e-01, -7.90634151e-01,
       -5.23598776e-01, -2.61799388e-01, -4.44089210e-16,  2.61799388e-01,
        3.14159265e-01, -4.44089210e-16,  2.61799388e-01,  5.23598776e-01,
        8.11578102e-01,  8.16814090e-01,  8.22050078e-01,  8.27286065e-01,
        8.32522053e-01,  8.37758041e-01,  8.42994029e-01,  8.48230016e-01,
        8.53466004e-01,  8.58701992e-01,  1.04719755e+00,  1.30899694e+00,
        1.57079633e+00,  1.62315620e+00,  1.62839219e+00,  1.63362818e+00,
        1.63886417e+00,  1.64410016e+00,  1.64933614e+00,  1.65457213e+00,
        1.65980812e+00,  1.66504411e+00,  1.67028009e+00,  1.67551608e+00,
        1.68075207e+00,  1.68598806e+00,  1.69122405e+00,  1.69646003e+00,
        1.70169602e+00,  1.91637152e+00,  2.09439510e+00,  2.61799388e+00])

PS_data2 = array([3.25876564e+00, 3.81409794e+00, 1.11474756e+03, 8.12689697e+02,
       1.20040924e+04, 9.14052161e+03, 2.39588219e+04, 2.58246107e+05,
       2.25913494e+05, 2.00792586e+04, 7.48461712e+04, 7.79328551e+04,
       1.78038258e+04, 1.24493550e+04, 2.49796877e+03, 3.03134727e+03,
       3.66156269e+02, 5.77324315e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.44609756e+01,
       4.28032233e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.44609756e+01, 4.21229883e+02,
       1.10116850e+05, 5.88833899e+04, 4.86932316e+03, 9.00693183e+05,
       4.35660173e+04, 1.12480933e+05, 6.37520293e+05, 1.45519285e+05,
       1.84586394e+04, 1.07850037e+05, 8.74590279e+03, 5.45370145e+03,
       9.68703597e+01, 1.96921122e+05, 1.89929087e+06, 2.66404045e+05,
       3.42301329e+05, 1.20854982e+06, 9.16540956e+05, 3.22951992e+06,
       9.83937935e+05, 1.27623169e+05, 1.38875057e+05, 3.03198348e+05,
       1.66383588e+05, 3.25265340e+04, 2.45382866e+03, 5.44667942e+04,
       9.83374694e+04, 2.93687201e+02, 3.75552805e+00, 4.48805516e+00])
```

Comment: Hard to tell anything without any data. It depends on the noise, the density, etc. You may find something with some hysteresis strategy (you call "peak" a point that is bigger than any other points of the "area". And "area" are delimited by points that are below α×lastPeak, α being a parameter). But if the data are not very dense x-wise, and noisy y-wise, it could not work.

Comment: In `print(w[peaks][max_peak_index])`, what's `w`? It's not defined in your code.

Comment: `I want an individual peak to be the combination of the data points.` Sounds like you could be more selective in what you define as a 'peak' by altering the threshold or prominence values. By default find_peaks() considers any point where the previous and next points are smaller to be a peak, no matter how small the peak is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array

Comment: @NickODell w is just the x values of my data. So that line prints the w value where the maximum peak Spectrum value occurs.

Comment: @jim_athon Can you edit the question to make it so that other people can run the code on their own computers, including enough data to demonstrate the problem? There's context missing from the question that makes it hard to answer.

Comment: @NickODell I have added a snippet of each of sets of data I was using. I hope this makes me question easier to answer.

Comment: Find the size and position of the maximum value in the data as the main peak. Take the extent of this peak as between the points to the left and right where it first drops below (say) 1% of the maximum. Now find the maximum of the rest of the data: if it is less than 10% (say) of the main peak then that main peak was prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question the following function should do the job:

```
def identification(x, y, ratio=10., prominence=1e5, distance=10):
    
    peaks, stats = signal.find_peaks(y, prominence=prominence, distance=distance)
    order = np.flip(np.argsort(stats["prominences"]))
    
    values = []
    
    if len(peaks) == 1:
        values.append(x[peaks[0]])
        
    elif len(peaks) > 1:
        for i, j in zip(order[:-1], order[1:]):
            if stats["prominences"][i] >= ratio * stats["prominences"][j]:
                values.append(x[peaks[i]])
    
    return {
        "values": values,
        "order": order,
        "peaks": peaks,
        "stats": stats,
    }
```

It scans for peaks, sort them by heights, then only keeps peaks which are `ratio` times taller than the next.

Following calls follow your observations:

```
identification(w_data1, PS_data1)
# {'values': [-1.5812683],
#  'order': array([0]),
#  'peaks': array([15]),
#  'stats': {'prominences': array([2087228.8524879]),
#   'left_bases': array([0]),
#   'right_bases': array([30])}}

identification(w_data2, PS_data2)
# {'values': [],
#  'order': array([2, 1, 0]),
#  'peaks': array([ 7, 27, 43]),
#  'stats': {'prominences': array([ 258242.84823436,  900596.3126403 , 3229516.16447195]),
#   'left_bases': array([ 0, 21, 21]),
#   'right_bases': array([18, 36, 54])}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do. My issue was not including `distance` in `find_peaks`.