# Efficient way to get the position info of the biggest item in a Python list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pythonic way to find maximum value and its index in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list)

Say, in list `[2, 3, 6, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7]`, I want to get `3` (position of item `9`) as output.

[A similar question but for numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584243/python-get-the-position-of-the-biggest-item-in-a-numpy-array)

My intuition is to build a tuple, and sort the tuple, and get the biggest item's position. I believe there are many better ways....

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, it is the solution. Didn't come up when I search. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pos = mylist.index(max(mylist))
```

This includes all internal python logic - Therefore the best possible implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
lst = [2, 3, 6, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7]
maxval = max(lst)
maxpos = lst.index(maxval)
```

Comment: ...which is one of the two answers in the linked question. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yep, I put the answer before seeing your comment.