# Find peak of 2d histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I make a 2d histogram of some `(x, y)` data and I get an image like this one:

[image: histogram-2d]

I want a way to get the `(x, y)` coordinates of the point(s) that store the maximum values  in `H`. For example, in the case of the image above it would be two points with the aprox coordinates: `(1090, 1040)` and `(1110, 1090)`.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from os import getcwd
from os.path import join, realpath, dirname

# Path to dir where this code exists.
mypath = realpath(join(getcwd(), dirname(__file__)))
myfile = 'datafile.dat'

x, y = np.loadtxt(join(mypath,myfile), usecols=(1, 2), unpack=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
ymin, ymax = min(y), max(y)

rang = [[xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax]]

binsxy = [int((xmax - xmin) / 20), int((ymax - ymin) / 20)]

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, range=rang, bins=binsxy)

extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[0], xedges[-1]]
cp = ax.imshow(H.transpose()[::-1], interpolation='nearest', extent=extent, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(cp)

plt.show()
```

---

**Edit**

I've tried the solutions posted by Marek and qarma attempting to obtain the coordinates of the bins rather than the index of them, like so:

```
# Marek's answer
x_cent, y_cent = unravel_index(H.argmax(), H.shape)
print('Marek')
print(x_cent, y_cent)
print(xedges[x_cent], yedges[y_cent])

# qarma's answer
idx = list(H.flatten()).index(H.max())
x_cent2, y_cent2 = idx / H.shape[1], idx % H.shape[1]
local_maxs = np.argwhere(H == H.max())
print('\nqarma')
print(x_cent2, y_cent2)
print(xedges[x_cent2], yedges[y_cent2])
print(xedges[local_maxs[0,0]], yedges[local_maxs[0,1]], xedges[local_maxs[1,0]], yedges[local_maxs[1,1]])
```

which results in:

```
Marek
(53, 50)
(1072.7838144329899, 1005.0837113402063)

qarma
(53, 50)
(1072.7838144329899, 1005.0837113402063)
(1072.7838144329899, 1005.0837113402063, 1092.8257731958763, 1065.3611340206187)
```

So the maximum coordinates are the same which is good! Now I have a small issue because if I zoom in on the 2d plot, I see that the coordinates are a little off-centered for both the global maximum and the local maximum:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: scipy.signal.argrelextrema ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13491866/624829

Comment: Possible solution: [Peak detection in a 2d array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array/3689710#3689710). Depending on your data, you may have to play with the size of the neighborhood, however.

Comment: That is an excellent question you point me to, thank you very much! I'll definitely check it out when I have some more time since it's quite long. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can find first global maximum

```
idx = list(H.flatten()).index(H.max())
x, y = idx / H.shape[1], idx % H.shape[1]
```

Finding coordinate of all maxima *was* left as exercise to the reader...

```
numpy.argwhere(H == H.max())
```

**Edit**

Your code:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, range=rang, bins=binsxy)
```

Here `H` contains histogram values and `xedges, yedges` boundaries for histogram bins. Note that size of `edges` arrays is one larger than size of `H` in corresponding dimension. Thus:

```
for x, y in numpy.argwhere(H == H.max()):
    # center is between x and x+1
    print numpy.average(xedges[x:x + 2]), numpy.average(yedges[y:y + 2])
```

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made and see if you can explain the offset I see?

Comment: Why is it `x + 2` and not `x + 1` if the `edges` array is one larger?

Comment: because `len(foo[1:1+2]) == 2`

Answer (score 3):

The library [`findpeaks`](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks/pages/html/Plots.html#two-dimensional-plots) can be of use.

```
pip install findpeaks
```

I do not see your data but let me try another similar example:

```
from findpeaks import findpeaks
```

[image: raw input data]

```
# initialize with default parameters. The "denoise" parameter can be of use in your case
fp = findpeaks()
# import 2D example dataset
img = fp.import_example()
# make the fit
fp.fit(img)
# Make plot
fp.plot()
```

[image: detected peaks]

The persistence can be of use to determine the impact of the peaks. You see that point 1, 2 and 3 show the strongest peaks, followed by the rest.

```
# Compute persistence
fp.plot_persistence()
```

[image: persitence plot]

Answer (score 2):

This question should help you: [Python: get the position of the biggest item in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584243/python-get-the-position-of-the-biggest-item-in-a-numpy-array)

You can use `H.max()` to get the maximum value and then compare it with `H` and use `numpy.nonzero` to find positions of all maximum values:  `numpy.nonzero(H.max() == H)`. This is going to be more expensive than just `H.argmax()` but you will get all maximum values.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made and see if you can explain the offset I see?