# Convert multiple columns into single column with output column giving colum nummber

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have this array in python:

```
     ([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

How to go about converting this 10 x 3 array to a 10 x 1 array with the single array being equal to the column number where there is a 1 in the row.  This output in this example case should be:

```
([2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int64)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as to how to do this in python.  Thank you!

Comment: `your_array.argmax(1)` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300334/understanding-argmax

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]
flattened = [x.index(1) for x in arr]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?