# Python Max/Position, array [[]]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array. I got the max value with `max = np.max(List)`. Now I need the position of the max value. I used this code:

```
x = np.where(a == a.max())
```

but it gives me that:

```
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([9], dtype=int64))
```

It contains the position but I don't know how to get it out of there. It would also be nice to know how to get the array below out of one of the two `[]`.

```
array([[10.39219 , 12.018309, 13.810752, 10.646565, 13.779528, 13.29911 ,
        13.650783, 12.464462, 13.427543, 14.388401]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the position of the biggest item in a multi-dimensional numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584243/get-the-position-of-the-biggest-item-in-a-multi-dimensional-numpy-array)

Comment: `where` gives the coordinates as 2 arrays.  It found one match at row `0` and column `9`.  Read `np.nonzero` docs for more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods:

1. Use `np.argmax`:

```
List = np.array([10.39219 , 12.018309, 13.810752, 10.646565, 13.779528, 13.29911 , 13.650783, 12.464462, 13.427543, 14.388401])
_max = np.argmax(List)
_max
>>> 9
```

2. Change to list and use `max` and `index` methods:

```
List = np.array([10.39219 , 12.018309, 13.810752, 10.646565, 13.779528, 13.29911 , 13.650783, 12.464462, 13.427543, 14.388401])
_max = List.tolist().index(max(List))
_max
>>> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

use `np.argmax()` to get the index

```
arr = array([[10.39219 , 12.018309, 13.810752, 10.646565, 13.779528, 13.29911 , 13.650783, 12.464462, 13.427543, 14.388401]], dtype=float32)
np.argmax(arr)
```